# Generate a .sparql file in order to backup rdf graphs

Tags: sparql, rdf, virtuoso

Is there a way to use SPARQL to dump all RDF graphs from a triplestore (Virtuoso) to a `.sparql` file containing all `INSERT` queries to rebuild the graphs?

Like the `mysqldump` command?

Answer (score 0):

RDF databases are essentially schemaless, which means a solution like `mysqldump` is not really necessary: you don't need any queries to re-create the database schema (table structures, constraints, etc), a simple data dump contains all the necessary info to re-create the database.

So you can simply  export your entire database to an RDF file, in N-Quads or TriG format (you need to use one of these formats because other formats, like RDF/XML or Turtle, do not preserve named graph information).

I'm not sure about the native Virtuoso approach to do this (perhaps it has an export/data dump option in the client UI), but since Virtuoso is Sesame/RDF4J-compatible you could use the following bit of code to do this programmatically:

```java
Repository rep = ... ; // your Virtuoso repository
File dump = new File("/path/to/file.nq");
try (RepositoryConnection conn = rep.getConnection()) {
    conn.export(Rio.createWriter(RDFFormat.NQUADS, new FileOutputStream(dump)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly enough, the [Virtuoso website](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) and [documentation](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/) include this information.

You don't get a `.sparql` file as output, because RDF always uses the same triple (or quad) "schema", so there's no schema definition in such a dump; just data.

The dump procedures are run through the iSQL interface.

To dump a single graph — just a lot of triples — you can use [the `dump_one_graph` stored procedure](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtRDFDatasetDump).

```
SQL> dump_one_graph ('http://daas.openlinksw.com/data#', './data_', 1000000000);
```

To dump the whole quad store (all graphs except the Virtuoso-internal `virtrdf:`), you can use [the `dump_nquads` stored procedure](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtRDFDumpNQuad).

```
SQL> dump_nquads ('dumps', 1, 10000000, 1);
```

There are [many load options](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtRDFInsert); we'd generally recommend the [Bulk Load Functions](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtBulkRDFLoader) for such a full dump and reload.

(ObDisclaimer: [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/) produces [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/), and employs me.)